# How to convert a shapefile into OSM .PBF format

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I have a large `.gdbtable` file (1.3 GB) with a road network that I would like to convert to `.PBF` format keeping the topology information.

I can load the `.gdbtable` file in QGIS so I thought it should be straightforward to write/export the file in `.PBF` but I cannot find this option. I would rather use QGIS to do this but an ArcGIS solution would be welcomed as well.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Converting anything non-OSM to PBF sounds wrong. Why do you need this?

Comment: I'm using a program that takes `.PBF` as an input. Different people may have different needs ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QGIS uses the [GDAL OSM driver](http://www.gdal.org/drv_osm.html), which is read-only. So no chance to write `.pbf` files directly.

You might look into http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Ogr2osm to get .osm files out of OGR supported formats.

To get a `.pbf` file, you can use [OSMconvert](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert) in a second step.